# Makefile - remove ../ from path

Tags: makefile

I have object files coming in with paths that might look like this:

```
 '../../src/foo/bar.c'
```

I'd like them to be output to

```
 'build/src/foo/bar.o'
```

Currently using:

```
 COBJS      :=  $(notdir $(CFILES))
 COBJS      :=  $(patsubst %,$(BUILD)%.o,$(COBJS))
```

I can achieve

```
 'build/bar.o'
```

This is problematic if any two library/project contains the same class name.

So the question is, how can one remove multiple '../' from a path in Make.  I've attempted the obvious and naive approaches with no results.

Update, the following will match exactly ../../ and replace it with the rest.  This is perfect except that it is specific to ../../.  Just need to make it match any number of ../../

```
 COBJS      :=  $(CFILES:../../%=%)
```

Update,

SOLVED, just three reputation shy of posting my own answer.

```
 COBJS      :=  $(subst ../,,$(CFILES))
```

Comment: What's wrong with `COBJS := $(subst ../.., build, $(CFILES))`?

Comment: Some files are not always two relative paths backwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As posted in my original question and I forgot to eventually answer.

The solution for this and likely many other Make string replacement is as follows:

```
COBJS      :=  $(subst ../,,$(CFILES))
```

'subst' takes 3 parameters.  $toMatch, $replaceWith, $string.

In this case $(CFILES) is the list of all .c files to compile.  I replace '../' with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try [abspath](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-abspath-625).

```
COBJS := $(foreach file,${CFILES},$(abspath ${file}))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to your problem can be as follows. Consider a simple Makefile

```
path_to_remove := batch1/test2
path_to_add := earth/planet

my_paths := \
batch1/test2/p/a3.c \
batch1/test2/p/a2.c \
batch1/test2/p/a1.c  \
batch1/test2/q/b3.c \
batch1/test2/q/b2.c \
batch1/test2/q/b1.c

$(info [Original] [$(my_paths)])
my_paths := $(my_paths:$(path_to_remove)/%=$(path_to_add)/%)
$(info [New Changed] [$(my_paths)])

all:
    @echo "Hi Universe"
```

When you run make command.

```
make
```

You will get ouput as:

```
[Original] [batch1/test2/p/a3.c batch1/test2/p/a2.c batch1/test2/p/a1.c batch1/test2/q/b3.c batch1/test2/q/b2.c batch1/test2/q/b1.c]
[New Changed] [earth/planet/p/a3.c earth/planet/p/a2.c earth/planet/p/a1.c earth/planet/q/b3.c earth/planet/q/b2.c earth/planet/q/b1.c]
```